# Triple integral using trapz over a part of a rectangular box

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying to evaluate a triple integral using the 'trapz' command in MATLAB. My integrand is function of gamma1,gamma2,s... I want to evaluate the integral numerically and not symbolically.

```
syms gamma1; syms gamma2; syms s
f=gamma1*gamma2*exp(-s*10);
x= -20:0.3:20;
y=linspace(0.1,100000,length(x));
z=linspace(0.1,100000,length(x));
[s,gamma1,gamma2] = ndgrid(x,y,z); 
mat=eval(f).* (gamma2>gamma1);         %MY QUESTION IS HERE
out = trapz(x,trapz(y,trapz(z,mat,3),2),1);
```

My question is I have a condition on my integrand, it should be evaluated ONLY when gamma2 >gamma1. Is my code correct above i.e is the way I add the logical statement correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the logic is correct: `mat` will have zeros where the condition `gamma2>gamma1` fails.

You can test correctness yourself by using an example where you know the answer already. For instance, integration of `f=gamma1*gamma2*s` within [0,2] in each variable gives 8 (with paper and pencil), and if the condition  `gamma2>gamma1` is added, the result is halved (by symmetry), so it becomes 4. And indeed, your code returns approximately 4 for this function.

---

As an aside: you may want to reconsider the desirability of using the same number of sample points in every dimension, given the disparity of sizes (40 by 100000 by 100000).

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to choose different number of sample points in every dimension, I think it gives an error if one trys to do that...can you please give an example...

Comment: Works for me: for example, `x= 0:0.01:2; y= 0:0.01:3; z= 0:0.01:5;` and the rest as before.

Comment: Thanks, works for me too. If you don't mind I have one more question, I have an extra condition of my function, I want s to be not equal to zero always. How can I add this logical operation to the above in addition to the one I have already ?

Comment: One way is to add another factor `.*(s>0)` to the evaluation of `mat`; however the more efficient way is to change the limits of integration from `-20:0.3:20` to `0:0.3:20`. This will save Matlab the trouble of computing the function in a region where you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks you, you see the integral that I am trying to approximate has limits over s,gamma1,gamma2 as the following [-inf,+inf],[0,+inf],[gamma1,+inf]... Do you see why I wrote the program as above?

Comment: I see. Unfortunately,  the integral you are trying to approximate **diverges**: its true value is infinity. This is why Matlab returns awfully large numbers; and the larger the limits, the larger the output will be.

Comment: Actually this is not my actually function, I have a much more complicated one which I can't write. But I was just worried about the logic of my code. @Behavious